# Why did Eve die with Maelon's data available?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I saved Wrex in ME1, I saved Maelon's data in ME2, the import screen in ME3 confirmed this.

When I get to the missions on Tuchanka, I completed every one of the side missions before starting the mission where they take down the Reaper and distribute the genophage cure.  Then when I finally get to the lab, Mordin tells me that Eve has died.

Yet every site I've been to says that keeping the data allows her to live.  So why did she die?

Comment: Was Mordin loyal by the end of ME2? I'm not entirely sure what effect that has on Eve, but it seems somewhat relevant.

Comment: @Ampersand - I don't think it's possible to both save Maelon's data and not have Mordin be loyal.

Comment: I think it's safe to say that this is a bug or you didn't save the data in the save you imported.

Comment: i know it's a silly question, but did you do ALL the side quests on tuchanka? with maelon's, if you do the genophage last (beware: last means you first do the bomb-disabling mission and then do the genophage part) there's no way Eve dies... except bugs, of course! the core mission here is the bomb one, since it's the one killing eve

Comment: I imported two careers from ME2 where I saved the data on both. Although, in one I let Maelon live and in the other I let him die. In both ME3 play-throughs, I did the exact same things, and Eve lived in the career where I let Maelon live, and Eve died in the career where I let Maelon die.

Answer (score 2):

If Wrex survived and you saved the data and you completed the bomb disarming mission and got that removed then Eve should live. Im afraid that sometimes import-glitches do occur and dont properly flag events. Either you didnt really save the data (if you got the message that she died from Mordin) or you are the victim of some glitch.