# Saved Maelon's Research Data but Eve dies from the stress & fatigue of the testing

Tags: mass-effect-3

My husband has played through to the genophage curing three times now and all 3 times Mordin tells Shepard that Eve has died from the stress and fatigue of the testing... However, in Mass Effect 2, he saved Maelon's research data and when importing the saved file, it even says the the data was saved..

He has also done all the quests before the genophage final quest. She does not get blown up by the bomb, she just dies from stress of the testing.
Does this mean he could have a glitch with his Mass Effect 2 save.. or is it a Mass Effect 3 glitch?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57359/why-did-eve-die-with-maelons-data-available

Comment: Actually its not exactly a duplicate question.. we are asking if this a glitch with his ME2 save or is something known with ME3.. He really doesn't want to play ME2 over since he's done it tons of times.. but if that's his only option he'll do it!. Sorry if it seems like a duplicate. I read the linked post before I posted, it did not answer my question.

Comment: There isn't an answer yet, but it describes the same bug, no?

Comment: Is Wrex still alive in your playthrough? I guess he must still be alive to save her..but since you said you had the same savegame for both playthroughs there must be antoher reason..

Comment: More research must be done to look into this. I talked to Eve and Mordin every chance I got and Eve never started coughing. I had an imported save from ME2 that had Mordin survive and Maleon's data saved. Eve still died of stress and fatigue.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug... but there seems to be a way around it.

In my first play though I did everything right in ME2. I saved the data and kept Mordin alive. During my first ME3 playthrough, Eve lived. No issues at all. On 2nd playthrough, I did everything the same as before and... Eve died?

Turns out that in the first playthrough I never went down to the lab to talk to Eve and Mordin, while in the second I made an effort to talk to both. That's when Eve starts coughing and she never did this before I went to the lab.

So don't go to the lab and talk to Eve. That should in effect not trigger the bug.

Comment: I don't think that this information is correct. I talked to Eve and Mordin extensively in the Medical bay and eve never started coughing and she survived. I think it is something else that triggers her demise. edit: or it is a bug that means she still dies

Answer (score 1):

You need a Mass Effect 1 save with Wrex still alive, and through Mass Effect 2 save Mordin & Maelon's data on the Normandy. Through Mass Effect paragon, be respectful as much as possible towards your allies & their choices.

Answer (score 0):

Ive played paragon all the way few a few times. Wrex and mordin live and are loyal, i saved maelons data, maelon lives. The difference is in talking to eve on every level the game allows you to on the way down from rescuing her from the salarian place.

Answer (score 0):

i think its a bug.
my 1st playthrough is pure paragon, everybody is loyal, alive and happy. eve survived. my 2nd playthrough, im kinda paragon, which is i kill all none essential, that includes Maelon but kept his research data,even rude to everyone i can, and eve lived to name their firstborn Mordin.

now i dont know if ur husband saved has wrex alive or pure renegade cause i dont have a save with wrex dead or pure renegade. hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

In the first playthrough were you good guys? because if so that's what allows you to calm her and make her less stressed and saying you're a friend etc. I think that's what allows you to let her live because in my first playthrough I was a good guy who destroyed maelons data and mordin died and eve lived I honestly think it's just the way you talk to her and treat her help her somehow i guess

Comment: 'You guess'? This answer is pretty vague.

Answer (score -2):

I think if you a renegade with her it stresses her out causing her to die from the stress you caused her I could be wrong, but she died on my renegade shepard and he also saved the data.

Comment: Were you waring the admiral clothes? Maybe she's stressed out by admirals!